# "Принесла нелегкая" — происхождение выражения

Tags: фразеология

"Кого еще нелегкая принесла?" — говорим мы о нежелательном госте. Но вот кто такая эта "нелегкая"? Судьба?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нелёгкая здесь сила, по другому её ещё "нечистой" называют. Чтобы не поминать лишний раз чёрта использовали подобный эвфемизм (сравните с "чёрт принёс").