# Кто такая «кривая» и почему она вывозит?

Tags: этимология

Выражение «вывезет кривая» обычно употребляется в случае надежды на удачу, в значении «авось».
Есть еще варианты «куда кривая вывезет» и «как кривая вывезет» с похожими значениями.
А откуда взялось это выражение?

Отрывок из хорошей песни с иллюстрацией, как кривая *не* вывезла:

> Взвыл я, душу разрывая:
>   «Вывози меня, Кривая, —
>   я на привязи!
>   Мне плевать, что кривобока,
>   Криворука, кривоока, — 
>   только вывези!»
>   Влез на горб к ней с перепугу, —
>   Но Кривая шла по кругу —
>   ноги разные.
>   …

Comment: Про «нелегкую» из этой песни можно почитать на [rus.se](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21860/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сообщает нам [Справочник по фразеологии](http://frazeolog_ru.academic.ru/229/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82),

> Полная форма выражения – куда кривая лошадь вывезет, где “кривая” значит “хромая”. Поехать на такой лошади – дело рискованное: она может довезти, а может и не довезти до места назначения.

Мы можем предположить, что ко времени написания Высоцким процитированной песни про лошадь уже помнили только словари.

Comment: Лошадь - да, а вот "дело рискованное" - явно надумано. И кто это "мы"?

Answer (score 0):

Это сокращенный вариант оборота "куда кривая лошадь вывезет".

Считалось, "кривая" ("хромая") лошадь могла вывезти куда угодно. И все выражение означало "не разбирая дороги", "не имея цели (движения)". Сравните: "куда глаза глядят".

Со временем стало относиться не только к физическому движению, и тем самым потерялась прямая связь с лошадью. Первичным стало значение "положиться на судьбу", "довериться случаю". Общим со старым значением осталось представление о движении "на авось", но если исходно общий настрой был фаталистическим, то ныне - скорее оптимистическим.

Да, насчет Высоцкого. При всем к нему уважении, он довольно часто доверялся вульгарному, а то и своему собственному пониманию слова или оборота. Хотя, кто знает, может делал это и сознательно, стилизуя, иронизируя или откровенно высмеивая такую псевдо-народную речь. В любом случае его трактовки бывают далеки от научных. "Криворукая лошадь" - это стилистический нонсенс. Если, конечно, "лошадь" - не эпитет девушки или еще кого.

Comment: так у Высоцкого Кривая и Нелегкая — это старухи:
  «И *огромная старуха*
 Хохотнула прямо в ухо,  злая бестия.
 Я кричу, - не слышу крика,
…
 "Кто здесь?" Слышу - отвечает:
                         "Я, Нелегкая!» 
  и в конце
  «И припали *две старухи*
 Ко бутыли медовухи -
                         пьянь с ханыгою…»
 Мне кажется, в данном случае он не стилизировал сознательно,  а просто воспринимал оба выражения как есть, а не как нелегкую силу или кривую лошадь. И я тоже по лошадь не знала,пока не заинтересовалась.

Comment: @user244413, да может быть, конечно, большие поэты имеет право на собственное виденье. Моя мысль была та, что не следует воспринимать как источник этимологической истины.